# Probability predictions from a saved LGBMClassifier model

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I trained a `LGBMClassifier` model and saved it to a file thus:

```
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier( ... )
clf.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
clf.booster_.save_model("model1.txt")
```

Now what I want is to re-use the saved model for probability predictions. But if I try:

```
## new predictions:

    clf_fs = lgb.Booster(model_file='model1.txt')
    y_pred2 = clf_fs.predict_proba(X_data2, num_iteration=clf_fs.best_iteration_)[:, 1]
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Booster' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

I understand that `cls_fs` is an object of class `Booster` and not of a class `LGBMClassifier`, and that I can use `clf_fs.predict()`, but not `predict_proba`. So how I can get back a `LGBMClassifier` object from the saved model file and generate proba predictions?

Answer (score 5):

In the [#1217 issue at Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1217) on this, Guolin Ke, one of LightGBM core  developers [said](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1217#issuecomment-413531615):

> `booster.predict()` actually will return the probabilities

so you shouldn't be needing `predict_proba`.